# ReactJS - Booking Website / Filtering for Date and Price

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot

I am currently working on a project. It is a website for booking rooms like AirBnB or Booking.com
I work with Java Spring as backend and frontend with ReactJs.

Most of the code is running as it should but I still have some problems at filtering for the date (Date Picker in React) and also for the price and the amount of rooms. The Date picker should check the availability of the rooms.

Currently i implemented it with a button but the filters change in running time, so the problem is they are not working together...

Maybe i just show you my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {RoomContext} from '../context'
import Title from '../components/Title';
import "react-date-range/dist/styles.css";
import "react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

//get all unique values
const getUnique = (items, value) => {
    // set only accepts unique values
    return [...new Set(items.map(item => item[value]))]
}
const getAvailableApartments = (availableApartments, value) => {
    return [...new Set(availableApartments)]
}

export default function RoomFilter({rooms}) {
    const context = useContext(RoomContext)
    //value from my inputs
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
    const history = useHistory();
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [availableApartments, setAvaiableapartments] = useState([]);

    const selectionRange = {
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: endDate,
        key: "selection"
    };

    function handleSelect(ranges){
        setStartDate(ranges.selection.startDate);
        setEndDate(ranges.selection.endDate);
    }
    const {
        handleChange,
        capacity,
        price,
        minPrice,
        maxPrice,

    } = context;

    const handleChange2 = (event) => setStartDate(event.target.startDate);
    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        axios
            .post("/api/availableapartments", {
                startDate: startDate,
                endDate: endDate
            })
            .then((res) => {
                setAvaiableapartments(res.data);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }
    //get people
    let people = getUnique(rooms, 'capacity');
    people = people.map((item, index) => {
        return <option key={index} value={item}>{item}</option>
    })


    //get apartmentIds
    let id = getUnique(rooms, 'id');
    id = id.map((item, index) => {
        return <option key={index} value={item}>{item}</option>
    })

    let availableApartment = getAvailableApartments(availableApartments, 'availableApartment');
    console.log(availableApartment);



    return (
        <section className="filter-container">
            <Title title="search rooms"/>
            <form className="filter-form">

                {/*guests*/}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="capacity">Guests</label>
                    <select
                        name="capacity"
                        id="capacity" value={capacity}
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={handleChange}>
                        {people}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {/* end guests*/}
                {/* room price*/}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="price">
                        room price ${price}
                    </label>
                    <input type="range" name="price" min={minPrice} max={maxPrice} id="price" value={price}
                           onChange={handleChange} className="form-control"/>
                </div>
                {/* end room price*/}
                {/* room date picker*/}
                <div className="form-group">
                    <DatePicker
                        selected = {startDate}
                        onChange = {date => setStartDate(date)}
                        selectsStart
                        startDate = {startDate}
                        endDate = {endDate}
                        ranges = {[selectionRange]}
                    />
                    <DatePicker
                        selected = {endDate}
                        onChange = {date => setEndDate(date)}
                        selectsStart
                        endDate = {endDate}
                        minDate = {startDate}
                        ranges = {[selectionRange]}
                    />


                        <div>
                            <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Search Apartments</button>

                            {availableApartments && availableApartments.map((apartment) =>  {
                                return (
                                    <div className="datepickersearch--availableapartments-container-card">
                                        <li>{apartment.apartmentNumber}
                                        </li>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                            }
                        </div>
                </div>
                {/* end date picker*/}

            </form>
        </section>
    );
}
```

I still think the error is within my React Code but maybe it is also relevant to show the test data in my data.sql and the Implementation within the backend.

data.sql

```
INSERT INTO "reservation" (id, apartment_id, billing_address, check_in_date, check_out_date, has_room, no_guests, payment, price, reservation_number, email)
VALUES (1, 1, 'testreservation', '2021-05-29','2021-06-03', true, 12, true, 12.9, 1234,'admin@vacationhome.com');
```

Implementation in my AppartmentController

```
   @GetMapping(value = "api/availableapartments")
    public List<Apartment> getAvailableApartments(@RequestBody String request)throws JSONException, ParseException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(request);
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date startDate = format.parse(String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("startDate")));
        Date endDate = format.parse(String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("endDate")));
        return apartmentService.getAvailableApartments(startDate, endDate);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. OnChange of the date you are updating the state of the start or end dates accordingly which will re-render the component but the data won't change as you are making API call only on submit.
2. To check is there any problem in the java code you can just console.log data and check whether the data returned is correct only then you can assume the problem is with the react code.
3. On filter change which functionality is not working can you elaborate on that.